# Scroll through a table and scrape all of its content using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to extract all the content from the tables displayed from Pg1-17 in the 'Microbe individual reconstructions' page. So far, I'm able to automatically load all the pages using Selenium- but the problem is that I'm unable to scrape the last 4 rows. I hope to use the Selenium scroll function and scrape the data, but the scroll seems to stop working halfway of the 1st page. What is the best way to scroll through the table of each page and extract data from all the rows/columns?

URL = https://www.vmh.life/#downloadview

Here's what I got so far, I'd be grateful for your advice! Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://www.vmh.life/#downloadview'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

microbe_button = driver.find_element_by_id("tab-1281-btnEl")
microbe_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

organism = []
reconstruction = []
genes = []
reactions = []
metabolites = []

while True:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for child in soup.find_all('td',attrs={'data-columnid':'gridcolumn-1251'}):
        organism.append(child.text)

    for child in soup.find_all('td',attrs={'data-columnid':'gridcolumn-1252'}):
        reconstruction.append(child.text)

    for child in soup.find_all('td',attrs={'data-columnid':'gridcolumn-1253'}):
        genes.append(child.text)

    for child in soup.find_all('td',attrs={'data-columnid':'gridcolumn-1254'}):
        reactions.append(child.text)

    for child in soup.find_all('td',attrs={'data-columnid':'gridcolumn-1255'}):
        metabolites.append(child.text)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "button-1266-btnIconEl"))).click()
    except:
        print('no more next pages')
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Organism': organism,
     'Reconstruction': reconstruction,
     'Genes': genes,
     'Reactions': reactions,
     'Metabolites': metabolites
    })
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The webpage you are referring has an [API](https://www.vmh.life/_api/reconstructions/) available.

If you are not necessarily bound to using selenium, you can easily and more accurately extract the information you need using [the python requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html)

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url='https://www.vmh.life/_api/reconstructions/?organismtype=Microbe')

for i in r.json()['results']:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
{'model_id': 375, 'createdDate': '2018-05-31T16:11:49.553912Z', 'updatedDate': '2019-01-22T18:39:48.823762Z', 'name': 'Citrobacter_youngae_ATCC_29220', 'descname': 'Citrobacter youngae ATCC 29220', 'organism': 'Citrobacter youngae ATCC 29220', 'organismtype': 'Microbe', 'author': 'Stefania Magnusdottir, Almut Heinken, Eugen Bauer, Ines Thiele', 'notes': '', 'version': '1.03'}
{'model_id': 376, 'createdDate': '2018-05-31T16:11:49.553912Z', 'updatedDate': '2019-01-19T09:31:48.548350Z', 'name': 'Clostridium_difficile_NAP08', 'descname': 'Clostridium difficile NAP08', 'organism': 'Clostridium difficile NAP08', 'organismtype': 'Microbe', 'author': 'Stefania Magnusdottir, Almut Heinken, Eugen Bauer, Ines Thiele', 'notes': '', 'version': '1.03'}
{'model_id': 377, 'createdDate': '2018-05-31T16:11:49.553912Z', 'updatedDate': '2019-01-18T17:41:35.504332Z', 'name': 'Enterobacter_cancerogenus_ATCC_35316', 'descname': 'Enterobacter cancerogenus ATCC 35316', 'organism': 'Enterobacter cancerogenus ATCC 35316', 'organismtype': 'Microbe', 'author': 'Stefania Magnusdottir, Almut Heinken, Eugen Bauer, Ines Thiele', 'notes': '', 'version': '1.03'}
...
```

To go to the next page:

```
r = requests.get(url=r.json()['next'])
```